# Routing error with an action while converting routes from rails2 to rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am converting my rails2 routes file which is in this format

```
 resources :levels ,:collection => {:search =>[:post,:get],:options => :get,:import_csv=>:get,:export=>:get,:upload_csv=>:post,:new=>:get,:edit=>:post,:options => :post}
```

to rails3 rest format

```
 resources :levels do
  collection do
    post 'search' 
    get 'options'
    get 'import_csv'
    get 'export'
    post 'upload_csv' 
    post 'options'
 end
  member do

  end
end
```

and I am defining this in my helper file i.e

```
html << link_to('Import Csv',{:controller=>'levels',:action =>'import_csv'})
```

the file doesnt go to action and instead going to 'show' and this is what I am getting the error:

```
  ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in LevelsController#show
  Couldn't find Level with ID=import_csv
  app/controllers/levels_controller.rb:23:in `show'
  Request Parameters: {"id"=>"import"}
```

Answer (score 0):

With this setup you should automatically have an URL helper for your custom collection actions, so you should use:

```
link_to('Import CSV', import_csv_levels_url())
```

Check with `rake routes` with route helpers you actually have.